# Call VS Called (conditional)

Tags: verbs, sentence, conditionals

I've been searching for examples/questions for this but found nothing.

Given the sentence:
'**I would put it on hold as soon as you call(ed) me**'

Should it be *call* or *called*?

The idea around this sentence is based on a condition: *If you call me, I put what I'm doing on hold*. 
But having the *would* implies a future condition, so I'm not sure what verb form to use here. Also, the *as soon as* makes it even more confusing to me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: They are both correct. It depends entirely on the frame of reference from the future point in time. (At the point in the future, will it already have happened, or will it be happening?) So, take your pick, based on what you're trying to express specifically—or whichever sounds better to you.

Comment: Ok I guess I get your point. If I use *call*, in this context, it means that I put smth on hold in that exact moment. On the other hand, if I use *called*, then I would be putting smth on hold after I get the call. Is that it?

Comment: Yes, that's right. (1) "Oh, I hear you calling. I'll put it on hold." (2) "Oh, I heard you call. I'll put it on hold."

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To clarify, "would" simply means that something is *conditional*. Obviously, conditional actions need a certain criteria to be met before being executed. So, yes, in a sense, "would" will always mean that something *is going to* happen – but it doesn't necessarily have to happen; you could be describing something in the past. Let me explain:

If you are describing a conditional action in the past, then you could write: **I would *have* put it on hold as soon as you *had* called me**. Notice that since we are in the past, we use "called" instead of "call". Also notice that you're saying what you would have done. It's too late to do it now. All you can do now is tell people an alternate scenario of what could have happened.

Otherwise, in the present, the conditional action would be written as: **I would put it on hold as soon as you call me**.

Finally, "as soon as" can be replaced by "immediately after". For example, we could rewrite your sentence as: *I would put it on hold immediately after you call me*.